# Wordpress Edit Page Page builder moved to the side

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Wordpress Theme Financity and somehow I moved my Page Builder and Page options to the side and they are displaying in the sidebar. Trying to drag it back and it's not working. It's driving me crazy! Please[image] Help.It used to be there before and display in full width.... How do i fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a drop and drag function. Have you tried looking at the plugin settings? Or tried deactivating the plugin and activating it again?

Edit: You can also click the three dots in the right top corner and select "Options" (which is probably the last item on the list). There you can activate and deactivate blocks.

Comment: tried checking the settings. If I deactivate the theme will my design be gone?

Comment: No, theme and plugin settings will always be saved in the database. Deleting a theme or plugin does not delete database settings. That being said, it's always good to work with back-ups.

Comment: unfortunately, deactivating the plugins did not help ;(

Comment: Have you tried dragging the screen beneath the editor? The arrow you drew is pointing into the WordPress editor, but Page Builders usually go beneath. If this doesn't work I could try to help using TeamViewer if you'd like me to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install classic editor plugin and activate in that page you can drag it below the page builder was in your right side of your page. When your done dragging it you can deactivate the classic editor.

[page builder in right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtL6F.png)

[fixed page builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPqJa.png)